# What was the name of anime in the opening of Malcolm in the middle?

Tags: malcolm-in-the-middle

What was the name of the anime showcased in the opening of Malcolm in the Middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anime featured in the opening of Malcom in the Middle is [Nazca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazca_(TV_series)).

> Anime guy smiling in the rain: [The character Shiogami from the movie **Nazca**](https://youtu.be/-k7qgQHl97s?t=19).
>
> Anime Guy Skateboarding: [Another scene from **Nazca**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKVeI8j0TrU).

Source: https://malcolminthemiddle.fandom.com/wiki/Opening_Sequences